# Azure B2C with domain hint instead of IdP buttons

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure B2C solution that federates login to a couple of ADFSs and Azure ADs as identity providers.
Currently they are all shown as buttons on login page. My customers do not like this because they can now see who else is using the service and who is not.

Is it possible to use domain hint with B2C instead of claims provider buttons?
A user types it's email address and then be redirected to "home" ADFS page based on domain in email to type a password. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Domain Hint is possible. You can configure URLs not to show IDP selection page at all.

Follow: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml

In above, base policy already configured for Facebook domain. (Snapshot below)

```
<ClaimsProviders>

        <ClaimsProvider>
      <!-- The following Domain element allows this profile to be used if the request comes with domain_hint 
           query string parameter, e.g. domain_hint=facebook.com  -->
      <Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
```

Try your policies follow same and enable domain_hint.

Once you configure you need to append domain_hint for your runnow URL. In Facebook case your run now URL going to be like (after appending domain_hint)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={policyid}&client_id={appid}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri={redirecturi}&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&domain_hint=facebook.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But then I need to know the domain BEFORE redirect to run now page. How is it possible? Since user doesn't enter an email yet. We have multiple identity providers. The only way I can see is that application itself asks for email first and then redirects to run-now URL.

Comment: I do believe your end users use a client application from where they will try login. Example: You have Applicaiton1 and have SignIn button. If I am not wrong you would have configure that SignIn button to redirect IDP selection page (where use see all IDP buttons). Now you (or owner of the client app) need to modify SignIn configured URL to append domain_hint. Once they configure domain hint and SignIn button from client app will auto take to specific IDP Login page.