# Azure B2C: how to Include domain hint in Sign Up/In links from asp.net core control

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using Azure B2C, I would like to use Google to sign in users. I would like to do something like this in my asp.net core page to achieve it:

```
<a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" asp-route-domainHint="google.com">Google Sign Up/In</a>
```

So that the Google challenge page is used to sign in the user.

However, this code results in the non-social ("organic") sign in page being used, instead, because the domain_hint parameter is not included in the auth redirect.

Looking at the account controller code, here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs

The only way to pass a domain hint to the Account controller, is by using the Challenge action.

```
<a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Challenge" asp-route-domainHint="google.com">Google Sign Up/In</a>
```

This almost works.

But it loops back again to Google challenge page, after you choose your google account, repeatedly.

Is there a way to pass a domain hint and use the SignIn action of the Account controller? Or some other approach for generating Sign In calls from an asp.net core page and include a domain hint?

I have seen this answer, but would prefer to not build up the entire href address from scratch: [Azure B2C with domain hint instead of IdP buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715835/azure-b2c-with-domain-hint-instead-of-idp-buttons)

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jas Suri's answer helped quite a bit, but there are a few code-related steps that I did to complete the solution:

To get that domain_hint parameter into the authentication link, you add some code to the ConfigureServices() method of the Startup class of your ASP.NET Core project:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); // Assuming an appsettings.json section named AzureAdB2C with config data
        options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc;
  });
```

The key part was subscribing to the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event. Add an event handler for it in Startup.cs, which  could look like this:

```
private async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc(RedirectContext context)
{
    var domainHint = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["domainHint"];
    context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = domainHint.Count > 0 ? domainHint[0] : null;
    await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The middle line above gets the domainHint from the query string. So, you must set its value in your razor view as follows. Take note of the asp-route-domainHint attribute, which ASP.NET Core adds to the rendered Href as a query string value.

```
<a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" asp-route-domainHint="google.com">Google Sign Up/In</a>
```

In the final rendered HTML, this link becomes (note the domainHint querystring parameter):

```
<a href="/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn?domainHint=google.com">Google Sign Up/In</a>
```

When a user clicks on that link, the Account controller in Microsoft.Identity.Web will redirect the user to the authentication link with Microsoft (note the domain_hint parameter near the end) which results in the social auth provider's screen being full-screen:

```
https://your-ADB2C-intance/your-ADB2C-domain/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=..etc..etc....&domain_hint=google.com&state=..etc..etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect users to an external identity provider, do the following:

1. Check the domain name of your external identity provider. For more information, see [Redirect sign-in to a social provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider).
2. Complete the [Support advanced scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#support-advanced-scenarios) procedure.
3. In the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc function, add the following line of code to the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider function:

```cs
private async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderFunc(RedirectContext context)
{
  context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "facebook.com";

  // More code
  await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#preselect-an-identity-provider

Comment: Thank you very much! This got me about 90% of the way there. I had to do a few more steps, which I will add in a secondary answer for those who are interested.