# Azure B2C - Capture an email address during signup without domain

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am looking to capture an email address from a specific internal domain during signup, but I don't want to users to enter the domain portion of the address. However I am trying to figure out the best way to signal the user to NOT enter the domain.

I would like to customize the default login page to include the domain shown after the textbox, something like below.

[image]

I know I could write a whole custom UI page to do this, but I was hoping to be able to do this with just a simpler customization of the default UI. Is this possible?

Comment: Requires custom html css and js. You could also use claimTransforms and predicates to handle either way the user enters their email.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was worried about. I think I am just going to use a regex restriction to force them to enter the domain we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please use the **‘login_hint’** and **‘domain_hint’** query parameters in the 2C custom policy regarding the need to **show a domain name during the signup user flow**. By specifying the `‘login_hint’ parameter in the signup custom policy, Azure AD B2C automatically populates the sign-in name while the user only needs to enter the password for his credentials though the user gets the option to change the sign-in name that is automatically populated from the custom policy to enter the sign-in name of his choice`.

Similarly, regarding the domain, `the ‘domain_hint’ query parameter provides a hint by auto-populating the domain name for the social IDP for which the sign-in is recommended. These two options mostly satisfy your requirement of not requiring a user to enter the domain name during login`. Kindly find the below samples of the above query parameters for your reference: -

***Domain hint: -***

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<!-- Add the domain hint value to the claims provider -->
<Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
<DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
...
```

***Login hint: -***

```
 <ClaimsProvider>
 <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
 <TechnicalProfiles>
 <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- Add the login hint value to the sign-in names claim type -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
  </InputClaims>
  </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
  </ClaimsProvider>
```

For more information on the above, kindly refer the below documentation links: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy***

***[Azure B2C with domain hint instead of IdP buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715835/azure-b2c-with-domain-hint-instead-of-idp-buttons)***